# How to add last UIView at bottom of first UIView when views are in round hierarchy in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, custom-view, uicontrol

In given image how to add 5th wing at bottom of first but above 4th wing

[image: Please click here to see the image]

Comment: I don't think you can. You need a workaround (ie cheat)

Comment: It's mathematics time now. Do calculations to achieve it.